# printing out a base 2^32 number in base 10

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-systems

I wasn't really sure weather I should post this in here or in Stack Overflow, but I am creating a big_int class and have a vector of unsigned integers, each of them being 32 bit; this vector represents a single number of base 2^32.

I am looking for a way to print in the console the base 10 equivalent of this number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ummm... just print it by calculating $2^{32}$.  I guess I don't see any problem here.

Comment: As an example if the vector is $(1,2,3)$ is $1 \times 2^{64}+2\times 2^{32}+3$ the  the answer will be $18446744082299486211_{10}$. 

You may need extended precision in your computer program

Comment: You can write $2^{32}=10^{32\log_{10}(2)}=10^{32\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(10)}}$

Comment: the issue is that i am attempting to implement extended precision, so I cannot use extended precision to do it.

Comment: Convert your base-2 vector to a base-10 vector of digits (without compromising not-yet-extended precision).